# Stay on the same html page with output in django

Tags: html, django

I want an user to select few products in a dropdown menu and based on that display a chart on the same page. User should be able to select/ deselect the options again from the dropdown menu and then refresh it, for which I want to stay in the same page. [My requirement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BAm8K.jpg)

I have written the code, but since for a separate view in django I have to have a different url, its going to the specified url where my dropdown menu is no longer working.

I have rendered the same display page with context to the get the above, just my url is different.

How can i make it work and stay in the same url. If possible reload the same page with the output data. Below is my code.

index.html:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <h3>Select products:</h3>
            <form id="selectProduct" role="search" method="get" action="{% url 'selectedproducts' %}">
                <select name="parameters[]" data-placeholder="Choose products" class="chosen-select" multiple tabindex="4">
                    {% for p in productnames %}
                        <option value="{{ p.productname }}"> {{ p.productname }} </option>
                    {% endfor %}
                </select><br/>
                <label for="submit"></label><button id="submit" type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row"></div><br />
        <h3> Distribution of sales in the products:</h3>
    </div>
</div>
<p>{{ productList }}</p>
```

urls.py

```
url(r'^products/', views.productList, name='index'),
url(r'^selectedproducts/', views.selectedproducts, name='selectedproducts')
```

view.py

```
def productList(request):
    productnames = Products.objects.all()
    context = {
        'productnames': productnames,
    }
    return render(request, 'sales/index.html', context)

def selectedproducts(request):
    p = request.GET.getlist('parameters[]')
    context = {
        'productList': p,
    }
    # --- logic later for chart ------
    return render(request, 'sales/index.html', context)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would simply use chart.js.http://www.chartjs.org/samples/latest/charts/pie.html . You can click on the labels and the chart interacts. No need to reinvent the wheel. Here are other options:http://www.chartjs.org/samples/latest/

If you really want to make it the way you are currently doing it you have to search for Ajax/API Calls. With an Ajax call you can fetch information from other sites without reloading it.

Comment: thanks for the references, planning to use charts only :) right now i was mostly focused on displaying the chart on the same page as the selection bar, rather than go back again to make selections then refresh the chart.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `<form id="selectProduct" role="search" method="get" action="{% url 'selectedproducts' %}">` change to <`form id="selectProduct" role="search" method="get" action="{% url 'index' %}">` and mix the both functions like

```
def productList(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        p = request.GET.getlist('parameters[]')
        k = request.GET('parameters[]')
        productnames = Products.objects.all()
        context = {
            'productList': p, 'productnames': productnames, 'k':k,
        }
        # --- logic later for chart ------    
    else:

        productnames = Products.objects.all()
        context = {
            'productnames': productnames,
        }

    return render(request, 'sales/index.html', context)
```

This will return to the same page, if a method get exist then show the form again with the selectproduct if not just show the form. Let me know if this solved you problem

Edit in your template

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <h3>Select products:</h3>
            <form id="selectProduct" role="search" method="get" action="{% url 'selectedproducts' %}">
                <select name="parameters[]" data-placeholder="Choose products" class="chosen-select" multiple tabindex="4">
                    {% for p in productnames %}
                        {% if k == p %}
                            <option value=="{{ p.productname }}" selected> {{ p.productname }} </option>
                        {% else%} 
                            <option value="{{ p.productname }}"> {{ p.productname }} </option>
                        {% endif %}
                    {% endfor %}
                </select><br/>
                <label for="submit"></label><button id="submit" type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row"></div><br />
        <h3> Distribution of sales in the products:</h3>
    </div>
</div>
<p>{{ productList }}</p>
```

Comment: wow this worked, learned a new thing today, thank you so much :). Is there anyway I can retain the values in the select bar, right now after submit the box is blank again. I found some posts but all were using either forms.py or were for http post and not get.

Comment: If you liked the answer, accept and/or upvote it @starFire

Comment: Yes, there is a way, give a time and I'll post it, if the answer solved you problem pls accept and upvote

Comment: its throwing error: 'QueryDict' object is not callable in "k = request.GET('parameters')" thisline. k is a list, so shouldn't it be k = request.GET('parameters[]') and also k will be a list while p will be a single product, so will k == p work?

Comment: try with k = request.GET['parameters'] or k = request.GET.get('parameters')

Comment: to get the list of selected items: k=request.GET.getlist('parameters[]'), and i changed if condition to {% if p in k %} still not working :(

Comment: Give a k a selected value, not the list, and if condition is not the problem

Comment: k = request.GET('parameters[]') --> this doesnt work (error: 'QueryDict' object is not callable) because parameters is a dict so, it has to be GET.getlist. And sorry, I might be missing something but I dont get it how will I give k a single value, i mean its a multiple select so it might have more than one value, which will never be equal to single product iterating in the for loop.

Comment: k = request.GET['parameters[]'] try, you can get only the selected value, and not all the list

Comment: This was also throwing error. But i fixed the issue somehow, I am now sending productnames as a list to the template instead of db object and in the template I am checking if p in k. Finally its solved :) , took a lot of time :(